# Flutter landscape orientation layout

Tags: layout, landscape, flutter

How to set AppBar height in landscape mode so that it is not taking up for screen padding?

[image]

Is there a usual Flutter landscape layout Widget? Aforementioned problematic layout is as follow:

```
new Padding(
  padding: media.padding,
  child: new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new LimitedBox(
            maxWidth: 320.0,
            child: new Column(children: [
              _buildAppBar(),
              new Expanded(
                  child: new ModuleDrawer(
                widget.module.sugar,
                topPadding: 0.0,
              )),
            ]),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: new RecordList(
              widget.model,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could probably use the `primary` property of a Scaffold, in combination of detecting the orientation through a simple `MediaQuery`. So on landscape mode, set the `primary` flag to false to tell the `Scaffold` to not take status bar height into account when determining the `AppBar` height.

See [the documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/primary.html):

> Whether this scaffold is being displayed at the top of the screen.
>
> If true then the height of the appBar will be extended by the height of the screen's status bar, i.e. the top padding for MediaQuery.
>
> The default value of this property, like the default value of AppBar.primary, is true.

So in your case, something like this should do:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    final bool isLandscape = orientation == Orientation.landscape;

    return new Scaffold(
        primary: !isLandscape,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('AppBar title'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Text('Look at the appbar on landscape!'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Time saver ;) Thx. I use your solution to make flutter gallery animation widget work in landscape mode

Comment: Based on the use case, you can also use the [OrientationBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder-class.html). Instead of depending of the device's orientation, it's based on the proportions of the parent widget.